# Cannot use MySQL my.cnf file on Ubuntu 16.04 for mysql-5.7

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04, percona

I have installed percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7 on an Ubuntu 16.04 server, and mysql is running fine with the default config our of the box. However, when i try edit the my.cnf file, i get errors that the variables are unknown, e.g.,:

```
mysql: [ERROR] unknown variable 'datadir=/var/mysql/mysql'
```

I have tried to locate different my.cnf file on the server and tried to add the variables in one after the other, but seem to be getting the same error.

So my question is, where is the appropriate my.cnf file for MySQL 5.7 on Ubuntu 16.04? I have even tried in this: /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf localtion and get the following error:

```
[....] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!
```

Below is info related to possible MySQL 5.7 config files on my Ubuntu 16.04 server

```
ubuntu@db-test-1:~$ sudo find / -name my.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
/etc/alternatives/my.cnf
/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/my.cnf
ubuntu@db-test-1:~$
ubuntu@db-test-1:~$ sudo ls -l /etc/mysql/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 30 15:05 conf.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  237 Oct 30 12:42 debian.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  836 Oct 30 14:49 my.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  380 Oct 24 01:18 percona-xtradb-cluster.cnf
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 30 11:51 percona-xtradb-cluster.conf.d
ubuntu@db-test-1:~$ sudo ls -l /etc/mysql/conf.d/
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8 Oct 30 15:05 mysql.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 55 Jan 22  2017 mysqldump.cnf
ubuntu@db-test-1:~$ /usr/sbin/mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"^C
ubuntu@db-test-1:~$ sudo su
root@db-test-1:/home/ubuntu# /usr/sbin/mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

By the way, the debian.cnf file does not come with version 5.7, but i added it cos i need it for log rotate during flush logs.

Below is my galera config at added at the bottom of the /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf config file:

```
server-id = 1010101
# Galera Config
wsrep_cluster_address = gcomm://10.1.0.101, 10.1.0.101
wsrep_cluster_name = db-hr
wsrep_provider = /usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so    
wsrep_provider_options = "gcache.size=4G"
wsrep_slave_threads = 4
wsrep_sst_auth = "user:secret"
wsrep_sst_method = xtrabackup-v2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The my.cnf file is set in sections and this parameter should be set under the [mysqld] section. 
The error suggests that you might have it in the [mysql] or [client] section.
There is a free online tool that might help you create the my.cnf correctly, you do have to register your email to access it though: https://tools.percona.com/

There is a step-by-step example for Ubuntu that may help you through here https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/LATEST/howtos/ubuntu_howto.html

Comment: You are right. I somehow accidentally deleted the d at the end of [mysqld] and only had [mysql]. Works now. Big Thanks.

Comment: So after adding [mysqld]  ot op of my /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf config file, everyhting works fine. But when i try to add galera config at the bottom of the file to create a cluster (PXC), mysql is not reading the galera info. So when i do a show variable ... , i get the default settings and not the configured settings. Check the original post for my galera config:

Comment: Have added a link that might help clarify

Comment: The issue i have is not configuring Galera. I do this frequently with no problem as tens of our databases running on Ubuntu 14.04 use PXC. But we are planning to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 and in the middle of testing setting up a PXC environment using Ubuntu 16.04. And for some reason, nodes are not reading the galera config (ONLY the galera part) in the /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf file. Also tried to add the Galera config under /etc/mysql/conf.d/galera.cnf and still facing the same problem.